# Complicated queryset in django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on django 1.6 and I want to filter all `Activities` when Season's inactive is True.

This is possible with models below?
class Production hasn't ForeignKey to SeasonProduction and Season.

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    production = models.ForeignKey(Production, null=True, verbose_name='ProductionId')

class SeasonProduction(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, verbose_name='SeasonId')
    production = models.ForeignKey(Production, verbose_name='ProductionId')

class Season(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)
    inactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Production(models.Model):
    prod_info = models.CharField('ProductionInfo', max_length=255,
                                       null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=255)
```

Comment: May I ask why are you using Django 1.6. It's outdated and buggy.

Comment: Becasue project is in django 1.6 @gitblame

Comment: Can you post the `Production` model definition?

Comment: @gitblame Please check my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
season_prods = SeasonProduction.objects.filter(season__inactive=True)

activities = Activity.objects.filter(
    production__in=season_prods.values('production_id'))
```

Relevant docs links:

- [value Queryset method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)
- [in lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)